# Tip on how to use dependency walker

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, mfc, dependencies

I have a very simple dialog-based MFC project meaning that I have just created a dialog and then ran it. 
[image]
there's no problem and the code perfectly does well with the following configuration:

**Configuration : Active(Debug)

Platform : Active(Win32)**

But when I open the file `AB.exe` in `Dependency walker`, I get these errors:
[image]
Of course `Dependency Walker` shows these results:

**IESHIMS.DLL is not opened

all of the .dlls related to windows api have the CPU type x64

all of the other .dlls except the followings have the x64 type

AB.EXE and COMCTL32.DLL have x86 type**

- Should I care the `Dependency Walker`'s results?
- Is it possible to have .DLLs of different CPU types in one project?
- Based on the fact that the program runs perfectly, why does the
  walker shows these errors?
- Can you introduce me a good link to learn how `Dependency Walker`
  works?

Comment: Are you using the 32-bit version of Dependency Walker?

Comment: [Dependency Walker FAQ](http://www.dependencywalker.com/faq.html) and [Dependency Walker Help Contents](http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/contents.htm) will explain all the questions you have asked. Of particular interest should be [How to Interpret Warnings and Errors in Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/interpreting_errors.htm).

Comment: @Derek how can I understand whether I'm using a 32-bit version or a 64-bit? The `Dependency Walker` that I'm using is a portable one and there was no error when running it on a win7x64 system???

Comment: oh ok @Derek I checked, I have downloaded `Dependency Walker` as a 64-bit pack. No I'm using 64-bit version of `walker`

Comment: @sepideh Use the 32-bit version of Dependency Walker for "walking" 32-bit applications.

Comment: ok @Derek you say regardless of using a win7x64 system, I should use 32-bit `Dependency Walker` to walk programs that I have written with 32-bit configuration and if I have written my program with 64-bit configuration, I should use a 64-bit `Dependency Walker`.

Comment: @sepideh That is my understanding, yes. Please try the 32-bit version of Dependency Walker for your 32-bit application.

Comment: Read *Will Dependency Walker work with 64-bit modules?* from the Dependency Walker FAQ I linked above to understand why there is a 32bit and 64bit version of Dependency Walker and the implications it has on opening a 32bit or a 64bit module.